# concerns regarding exploring starts given my state is not the same as my observation space in gym

Tags: reinforcement-learning, openai-gym

My state for a custom Gym environment is not the same as my observation space. The observation is calculated from the state.

How will RL that requires exploring starts etc, work? Or do I get it wrong?
I imagine the algorithm to sample from my observation space and then setting the state of the environment and checking an action. But this will not work with my environment.

From the question above you see I'm newby with RL and with Gym. What RL should I use in above case? How would you address such a situation?

Any tips?

Answer (score 0):

My custom Gym environment is now selecting a random start state. Therefore, by using this environment, one can achieve "Exploring Starts". So, I do not need to worry any more that my observation is not the same as my state. For example, implementing Monte Carlo ES for Black Jack, as described in the RLbook2018, the state of my environment includes the hidden card of the dealer, while an observation does not.
I was confused at the time as I wanted the algorithm itself to pick the random state and set it into the environment.
PS,
If you need to save states of previous "alternative realities", search SO or Google for wrappers, and how they do that for MCTS (Monte Carlo Tree Search).